# Sum of logarithm reciprocals

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am looking for an exact formula for the sum :
$$\sum_{1<n\leq x}\frac{1}{\log n}$$
My attempt :
Using the Perron's formula for partial Dirichlet series, we have :
$$\sum_{1<n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^{s}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}(\zeta(s+\omega)-1)\frac{x^{\omega}}{\omega}d\omega$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{c^{'}-i\infty}^{c^{'}+i\infty}(\zeta(z)-1)\frac{x^{z-s}}{z-s}dz$$
Now, we have :
$$\sum_{1<n\leq x}\frac{1}{\log n}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{1<n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^{s}}ds=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{c^{'}-i\infty}^{c^{'}+i\infty}\left(\zeta(z)-1\right)\text{Ei}(z\log x)dz$$
$\text{Ei}(\cdot)$ being the exponential integral function. By the residue theorem, the smooth part of this sum is given by :
$$\text{Ei}(\log x)=\text{li}(x)$$
$\text{li}(\cdot)$ being the logarithmic integral function. My question is about the oscillatory part. How does one find an exact formula for this  oscillatory part ?

Comment: I'd be astonished if there were a closed form formula for this sum.

Comment: I think you can much better handle this function using the Euler–Maclaurin sum formula than by estimating a contour integral. (In a certain sense, that gives you an exact formula for the oscillating part, but probably not a useful one.)